# New pandas column based on multiple conditionals

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble with this - and don't quite understand why it's not working.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'X':[1],'Y':[1]}
d = pd.DataFrame(d)

dfc1 ={'1':[0.001,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.001]}
dfc1 = pd.DataFrame(dfc1)

xo = 6.525
yo = 5.55

d.loc[(d['X'] < xo) & (d['Y'] < yo), 'Start'] = dfc1.iloc[0]
```

running `d` after using this code, returns 'NaN' in a start column.

but if I changed it to

```
d.loc[(d['X'] < xo) & (d['Y'] < yo), 'Start'] = 0.001
```

then `d` returns the output I want which is the 0.001 in the start column.

What's the reason I'm unable to return the result of `dfc1.iloc[0]` as a value in a new column, and would there be a way I could do that instead of typing the 0.001 manually?

Thanks

Comment: `dfc1.iloc[0].values`

Comment: Incredibly easy. Thanks for your time!

Comment: `dfc1.iloc[0]` is a `pd.Series` when you need to assign the value using an array `dfc1.iloc[0].values`